# Next button is disabled in Import project window and other windows in eclipse. Not able to import a project

Tags: eclipse

I have newly installed eclipse in my machine.I am trying to import an eclipse project. When I click on Import option in File menu, a pop-up appears with Back,Next,Finish and Cancel. Only Cancel button is enabled and remaining three buttons are disabled in grey. 
This is also case with creating new project, When I click on Other from File New menu a New pop-up appears with Back,Next,Finish and Cancel buttons. Only Cancel button is enabled and remaining three buttons are disabled.It would be a silly mistake in installing, Please help me. I tried this for Helios,Mars and Neo.

Comment: You have to select something in the list in the center of the dialog in both these cases. Have you done that?

Comment: @greg-449 that list drop down itself is disabled

Comment: Show us a picture of what you are seeing